# BaseEntity class fields are not inherited by children

Tags: typescript, inheritance, nestjs, decorator, typeorm

In my NestJS app, I would like to create a `BaseEntity` class that every entity would extend. I have come up with the following class:

```js
export class BaseEntity {
  @ApiProperty({ example: 'c057cc8c-ad1b-4081-ba05-41a648e29f19' })
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @ApiProperty({ example: '2021-07-23T16:23:17+00:00' })
  @Column({ nullable: true })
  archivedAt: UTC;

  @ApiProperty({ example: '2021-07-23T16:23:17+00:00' })
  @Column({ nullable: false })
  createdAt: UTC;

  constructor(partial: Partial<BaseEntity>) {
    Object.assign(this, partial);
  }
}
```

But when I try to extend this class in the following way:

```js
@Entity()
export class Book extends BaseEntity {
  @ApiProperty({ example: 'Harry Potter' })
  @Column({ nullable: false })
  title: string

  constructor(partial: Partial<Book>) {
    super();
    Object.assign(this, partial);
  }
}
```

I get the error saying: 
`MissingPrimaryColumnError: Entity "Book" does not have a primary column. Primary column is required to have in all your entities. Use @PrimaryColumn decorator to add a primary column to your entity.`

It seems like the decorators are not inherited, thus the primary column is missing (and so are all the other fields). Do you have any other idea how to create a `BaseEntity` class? Appreciate your help :)

Comment: that's weird. I'm using the same pattern. I have a base class with `@PrimaryColumn()` working as expected

Comment: @MicaelLevi Thanks for pointing out it works fine for you. It appeared I was importing a `BaseEntity` class from `typeorm` instead of the one I created. Silly mistake, thank you :)